# Split element with diagonal line using SVG or CSS3

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to draw diagonal line using SVG. I managed to get it to work if the holding element(div in this case) has 100% width and height.

But I would need it to work on one div that has 50% width and height, basically I need this line to split the half of the page in half.

Here is the fiddle with 100% width and height: http://jsfiddle.net/cPMd7/

```
<div class="holder">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version='1.1' width="100%" height="100%">
<line x1="100%" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%" style='stroke: #000; stroke-width: 1'/>
 </svg>
```

Are there any other altrenatives to SVG, maybe CSS3 bg images or similar?

Comment: Can't you simply change dimensions to the div? The problem is not clear to me.

Comment: Can you show an example somewhere else of what you are after ?

Comment: Stupid me, I forgot something so trivial. Please change from absolute to relative positioning in the fiddle. It is not ok after that, all that is needed is to give body,html{width:100%;height:100%} and it is working after that. My issue was that the line was not drawn correctly when using relative positioning on the holding div.